# How would I display edittext field dynamically

Tags: android

I have a string array and I have to display the string array in a edittext box showing one value at a time.
For Instance,

```
String str = new String{"abc", "def", "ghi"};
```

I have to show these values in a edittext box such that the value keep changes periodically as soon as a user opens this activity.
Please help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is periodically?

Answer (score 1):

You can put this string array into parent activity of this activity. And wen you are starting intent of this activity(which contains edittext), put extra values i,e in your case array[i] and then start the activity.

starting intent from parent activity :

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
i.putExtra("STRING_you_NEED", string[i]);
```

and then get it on your activity that contains editText !

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 edittext.setText(extras.getString("STRING_you_NEED"))
```

Comment: Why do you assume he wants to pass data between activities?

Comment: he has mentioned that " as soon as a user opens this activity " , i assumed that he is coming from one activity and he want to do this stuff.
if he don't want to pass data between activities , he can do it with another answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to store an index to the string array and retrieve it whenever you want. Depending on the use case, you can try the following,

- Use SharedPreferences and use a key-value pair to store the index and retrieve it when you want to show the string in the Activity(Persistent)
- Extend your Application(or create a static class) and use a static int variable to store the index(Non-Persistent)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Kindly can you please elaborate, as I am new to android development.